# Changing button colors and sending a prop to child component on click with vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new with vue.js and trying to make a component work as a follows:

I have four buttons and after I click on one button I wanna change all four buttons colours and send a prop to a child component to inform it the button I choose.

My work as following:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-toolbar app>
      <v-toolbar-title class="headline text-uppercase">
        <v-flex>
          <v-btn class="mx-2" icon large>
            <v-icon dark @click="reloadPage" >home</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn class="ma-2" :ref="ModelA" :modelProps="modelA" @click="chooseModel(0)" rounded flat text > MODEL A </v-btn>
          <v-btn class="ma-2" :ref="ModelB" :modelProps="modelB" @click="chooseModel(1)" rounded flat text > MODEL B </v-btn>
          <v-btn class="ma-2" :ref="ModelC" :modelProps="modelC" @click="chooseModel(2)" rounded flat text > MODEL C </v-btn>
          <v-btn class="ma-2" :ref="ModelD" :modelProps="modelD" @click="chooseModel(3)" rounded flat text > MODEL D </v-btn>
        </v-flex>
      </v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    </v-toolbar>

    <v-content>
      <childComponent/>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import childComponent from './components/childComponent'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    childComponent
  },
  data () {
    return {

    }
  },
  methods: {

    chooseModel:function(model){

      switch(model){
        case 0:
          this.$refs["ModelA"][0].color = "rgb(0, 100, 0)";
          this.$refs["ModelB"][0].color = "rgb(100, 0, 0)";
          this.$refs["ModelC"][0].color = "rgb(100, 0, 0)";
          this.$refs["ModelD"][0].color = "rgb(100, 0, 0)";
          break;

        case 1:
          this.$refs["ModelA"][0].color = "rgb(100, 0, 0)";
          this.$refs["ModelB"][0].color = "rgb(0, 100, 0)";
          this.$refs["ModelC"][0].color = "rgb(100, 0, 0)";
          this.$refs["ModelD"][0].color = "rgb(100, 0, 0)";
          break;

        case 3:
          this.$refs["ModelA"][0].color = "rgb(100, 0, 0)";
          this.$refs["ModelB"][0].color = "rgb(100, 0, 0)";
          this.$refs["ModelC"][0].color = "rgb(0, 100, 0)";
          this.$refs["ModelD"][0].color = "rgb(100, 0, 0)";
          break;

        case 4:
          this.$refs["ModelA"][0].color = "rgb(100, 0, 0)";
          this.$refs["ModelB"][0].color = "rgb(100, 0, 0)";
          this.$refs["ModelC"][0].color = "rgb(100, 0, 0)";
          this.$refs["ModelD"][0].color = "rgb(0, 100, 0)";
          break;
      }
    }

  }
}
</script>
```

Why this is not working and What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `ref` is not a native HTML attribute so you can not bind it. However, it's a custom attribute that vue compiles, so you can use as a normal one.

Also the `$refs['modelA']` will have the reference for the Vue element, Vue.js wraps the native HTML elements as well.

Finally. you can store the choosen model in the vue data, and pass it as a prop to the child component.

I created a jsfiddle for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/z3qv1dtp/

Also, I recommend you use Vue data to store the button configuration and pass them as props to each button instead of mutating the Vue element directly.

https://jsfiddle.net/z3qv1dtp/1/